# Remote Desktop from Win10 -> Windows Server 2016 slow, but fast the other way around

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, network-adapter, windows-server, windows-server-2016

I am experiencing extreme latencies when using Remote Desktop from My Windows 10 machine into Windows Server 2016 Standard (Intel i210 internal NIC). Both are within the same network (1G connection). The latency is many milliseconds when typing or moving windows or doing just about any task from within the RDP window.

However, when I connect from Windows Server 2016 into my Windows 10 machine via RDP there is virtually no latency, everything is very smooth and fast. I pinged my Server machine from within Windows 10 and it does not show any latency, so I am suspecting it has something to do with my settings in Windows Server 2016 or in the Intel i210 NIC settings, or possibly it has something to do with the compression algorithms? Or does it help to use Jumbo Frames? I am confused because RDP works flawlessly when connecting from the server into Win10, but latencies the other way around make using RDP almost useless.

Connecting an RDP session is fast both ways around, it is the latencies when being logged into remotely and when typing or opening windows or panning windows.

I already installed TeamViewer on both ends to test and the same phenomenon is witnessed. That made me think that maybe it is not the RDP settings but something related to the Intel NIC settings?

Anyone can point me in the right direction?

Thanks

P.S.: No VMs involved, just a local server machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the latency issue: What really made the difference (for me) was to disable on both, the server and client side:

- IPv4 Checksum Offload
- Large Receive Offload
- Large Send Offload
- TCP Checksum Offload

Comment: Good to hear!  Please do us a favor and come back when the two-day waiting period is over to accept your own answer as the official solution.

Comment: How did you do this? In what device / application are these settings?

Comment: You can change those settings in the settings/properties of your network card device within device manager.

Comment: i do not have these config properties available for wlan(wifi) on client side. i have disabled them on server side.

Answer (score 0):

On the 2016 server, under **Local Policies/Security Options**, disable "Use FIPS compliant algorithms". That should fix it.

Comment: Could you please cite your source?

Comment: No impact for me, still significant latency when remoting into my Server

Answer (score 0):

Removing Windows Defender worked for me:

To remove Windows Defender using PowerShell:

1. Open PowerShell as Administrator.
2. Type the following command and press Type the following command and press Enter:

`Uninstall-WindowsFeature -Name Windows-Defender`

3. Restart the server.

https://www.wintips.org/how-to-disable-or-remove-windows-defender-antivirus-in-server-2016/

Comment: That is not a recommendable course of action, imho.